# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider -> because ui-router requests the wrong thing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I recently switched over to `ui-router` from `ngRoute` and nearly 90% of my code doesn't work anymore because of strange effects that shouldn't be there.

This is the constructor of one of my controllers:

```
 constructor(
        cameraApiService: ICameraApiService, 
        $log: ng.ILogService,
        $stateParams: any) {
```

With `ngRoute`, `ICameraApiService` (`class CameraApiService`) can be injected without problems. Now with `ui-router`, it fails to resolve `ICameraApiService`. Upon further investigation, I figured out that angular doesn't try to resolve `CameraApiService`, but `cameraApiServiceProvider`:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cameraApiServiceProvider <- cameraApiService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/unpr?p0=cameraApiServiceProvider%20%3CameraApiService
```

Which of course doesn't exist. Is there a difference between `ngRoute` and `ui-router` in terms of DI? Do things have to be declared differently?

BTW: I'm using `Typescript` and `grunt-tsng`. All dependencies/modules/services are registered.

Comment: can you show the part of converted .js file?

Comment: @elaijuh http://pastebin.com/Ke35CpRX

Comment: line 73: `controller: App.Cameras.CameraListController` should be `controller: 'App.Cameras.CameraListController'` ?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to your converted [.js](http://pastebin.com/Ke35CpRX) file , line 73: `controller: App.Cameras.CameraListController`. the controller here should refer to a string name like `controller: 'App.Cameras.CameraListController'`

Comment: Wow. It works! I assumed that I can declare the controller name strongly typed and typescript/tsng take about the rest.. since well, there should be a reason to use typescript. :/

Comment: know less about typescript/tsng tho... fan of plain ecma :p could you pls upvote/accept it if the answer is useful to you, thanks.